# Getting elevation data or Z value of point using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, 3d, elevation

I know that there is 3d drawing in QGIS. However, I want to learn that how it converts 2d map to 3d.

Is there a way to get height value of points or does it convert longtitude, latitude to xyz format?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a elevation surface as a raster, and some point data you can use the Point Sampling Tool (install as a Plugin).  The Point Sampling Plugin tool will create a new point dataset with a new column populated with the pixel value of the raster.  Best to have the vector and raster data share a coordinate reference system to avoid errors in the tool.  [Here is a tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/sampling_raster_data.html).